# Привязка Flask к домену

Tags: python, flask

Работаю через консоль (VDS), в панели привязал site.ru и теперь во время установки по [инструкции](https://flask-russian-docs.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/installation.html#installation) надо создать папку

```
$ mkdir myproject
```

Мне надо сразу указать домен как-то или сначала создать папку myproject и потом позже перекинуть проект?

Comment: Хз что там у вас, но в общем случае фласку плевать что как называется

Comment: @andreymal я сейчас запустил hello.py и в консоле пишет
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
как мне теперь увидеть?? Я ведь не локалке, а на удаленном сервере запустил скрипт

Comment: Если опускать матчасть, то лучше всего погуглить связку nginx, gunicorn и flask. А вообще, я так подозреваю, вы вообще не понимаете, что такое 127.0.0.1, что такое 5000 и как работает подключение к веб-серверу? Тогда вам лучше сперва почитать, как устроен интернет :)

Comment: или проксипасс на вэб сервере во фласк, или sgi интерфейс через гуникорн какой-нибудь - итайте про деплой проекта

Comment: попробуйте следующую страницу из инструкции прочитать (быстрый старт, развёртывание приложения на веб-сервере).